# How to add a Block diagram like the below in share Latex?

Tags: flow-charts

[image]

How to add such block diagram in the ShareLatex?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1cm,column sep=1cm,nodes=draw] (m) {
    Text & Text & Text \\
    Text &      & Text \\
  };
  \draw[->] (m-2-1) -- (m-1-1);
  \draw[->] (m-1-1) -- (m-1-2);
  \draw[->] (m-1-2) -- (m-1-3);
  \draw[->] (m-1-3) -- (m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]